# Does Quorum provide support for Windows?

Tags: quorum

I am new to Quorum.I want to build Quorum with windows.

But Windows isn't currently supported directly as stated in https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/178

Is there any alternate solution to use Quorum with windows?